# Macro to Copy/Paste data from txt files into new workbook is pasting into the Personal Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

The title more or less sums it up. I am trying to make a simple macro to open and then copy/paste data from txt files into a newly opened workbook. What I have work but it pastes it into the Personal Workbook at that opens before a new "Book1". I could make it paste to Book1 but I just want it paste it into the first workbook opened in case I want to add more data to the same file down the road. I am pretty new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
Public Sub ImportFile()
    Dim TextFile As Workbook
    Dim OpenFiles() As Variant
    Dim x As Integer
    
    OpenFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select File(s) to Import", MultiSelect:=True)
    
    For x = 1 To Application.CountA(OpenFiles)
    
    Set TextFile = Workbooks.Open(OpenFiles(x))
    
    TextFile.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
    Workbooks(1).Activate
    Workbooks(1).Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    TextFile.Close
    
    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It will create a new workbook. It will create additional worksheets with names "New1, New2 " etc. Hope it will help your requirement

```
Public Sub ImportFile()
    Dim TextFile As Workbook
    Dim OpenFiles() As Variant
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    
     OpenFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select File(s) to Import", MultiSelect:=True)
    
    For x = 1 To Application.CountA(OpenFiles)
    
    i = 1
    
    Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add
 
    Set TextFile = Workbooks.Open(OpenFiles(x))
    
    TextFile.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
    
    ws.Paste
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    
    ws.Name = "New" & i
    i = i + 1
    TextFile.Close       
    
    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code line, please:

```
Debug.Print Workbooks(1).Name
```

It will return "PERSONAL.XLSB".

So, if you use your code like it is, it will all the time copy in "PERSONAL.XLSB".

If you do not want using a new workbook and you like your initial approach, you can try:

```
   '...
   'your existing code
   TextFile.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy

   Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
   If Workbooks.count > 1 Then
      Set wb = Workbooks(2)
   Else
     Set wb = Workbooks.Add
   End If
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add
    'and always use this sheet to copy on it...
    'your existing code...
    '...
```